# ASP.NET MVC page rendering performance issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-2, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm doing a fine performance tuning of asp.net MVC 2 application (webforms as view engine, linq2SQl as orm layer).
I'm using mvc mini-profiler to profile page rendering.
I'm not use (at the moment) any output cache.

I notice a little strange behavior on almost all the pages of my site.

When I first hit a page it takes about **200ms** to render, where I have about **15ms** of db query time (a call to a stored proc).

All the subsequent hit to the same page are rendered in about **20ms**, where the query remains to about 15ms. So in this case I assume the page is rendered in about **6ms**.

If I don't hit the page for about **5 minutes** (and there isn't any other request) and I try now to hit the same page it takes **200ms** to render with all subsequent call in the order of **18-20ms**.
Also I have verified that **no IIS app pool recycling has happened**.

Is suspect that there is somewhere in the MVC framework a cache that are invalidated after some minutes and that needs to be fine tuned.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about your `<compilation debug="true">` setting in web.config? If you have debug=true, change to false.

Comment: The debug attribute is at the default value, so False.

Answer (score 2):

The default cache for webforms view location is 15 minutes or so.  You can increase this like so:

```
foreach (var viewEngine in ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<VirtualPathProviderViewEngine>())
{
    viewEngine.ViewLocationCache = new DefaultViewLocationCache(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
}
```

More details are available here: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/23/asp-net-mvc-view-location-and-performance-issue.aspx

Comment: It is surely an improvement but it not solve my problem, thanks.